# Can't custom carousel bootstrap css in codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

I have a carousel that showing the slide of an image. But the problems is this image have a different height. So I need to change the height of image without stretching it.

Here is my code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<!-- css bs-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('/assets/css/custom.css'); ?>">
<!-- css FA -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('/assets/css/all.css');?>">



<title>Document</title>


<!-- Javascript -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js');?>"></script>  
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="w-100" src="<?php echo base_url().'gambar/'.$slider[0]['gambar'];?>" alt="First slide" >
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="w-100" src="<?php echo base_url().'gambar/'.$slider[1]['gambar'];?>" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another problem that I realize is that I can't change any of bootstrap css value. I don't know but it's like my bootstrap won't be changed with anything.

Comment: you should use images having same height and width

Comment: You have to make some assumptions, either you give max-height to the image and cut the long images or you can stretch the short images. Best is to have equal height image. Not sure if there could be any other alternative fix different height images

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property `object-fit: cover` on the image to achieve this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Add the following to your custom CSS:

```
.carousel-item img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You can probably remove the `w-100` class from the `<img>` too.

The caveat is that the image may be cropped horizontally or vertically, depending on the aspect ratio.